# jquery this.attr(value) returns blank

Tags: jquery

Quick scenario: Got a series of input fields, on focus if default value it clears the field ready for input. On blur it tests for empty and sets the default value. First part (focus) works like a charm second part doesn't and I have stared at the code to long and have clearly become blind to my error.

HTML:

```
<label for="name">Navn: *</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Dit Navn"><br>
<label for="email">E-mail: *</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="eksempel@mail.dk"><br>
```

The jQuery that works:

```
jQuery("#dfwylf_Overlay input:text").focus(function(){
    if ( jQuery(this).attr("value") == jQuery(this).val() ){
        jQuery(this).val("");
    }
})
```

the code that doesn't work:

```
jQuery("#dfwylf_Overlay input:text").blur(function(){
    console.log(jQuery(this).attr("value"));
    //the above outputs empty
    if ( jQuery(this).val() == "" ){
        jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).attr("value"));
    }
})
```

Comment: Any reason to not use placeholder attribute?

Comment: Show your real HTML code, not an example please.

Comment: reason for placeholder was the language, to make it easier for you guys.

Comment: I was talking about input placeholder attribute, not sure what you are talking about

Comment: `placeholder` may not work on some browsers.

Comment: @Bharadwaj true but not a big deal as OP is using labels as he should

Comment: @a.wolff label also won't work in some browsers?

Comment: @Bharadwaj which ones??? Label is part of HTML1

Comment: @a.wolff I am asking you as you pointed `label` in "not a big deal as OP is using labels as he should". ok you are saying if not `placeholders` then labels will guide?

Comment: @Bharadwaj ya this was what i said

Comment: I switched to using placehodler as suggested and now the code works.. I think the problem is with the attr value vs val. 'Cause the placeholder/val works like a charm while the value/val fails on that specific page.

thx for pointing me towards the right solution

Answer (score 0):

i think You have issue with jquery framework use 1.9.1 or above version

```js
jQuery("input:text").blur(function(){
 
    //the above outputs empty
    if ( jQuery(this).val().trim() == "" ){
        jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).attr("value"));
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="someName" id="someId" value="a value">
<input type="text" name="someName2" id="someId2" value="another value">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery("#dfwylf_Overlay input[type=text]").focus(function(){
    if ( jQuery(this).attr("value") == jQuery(this).val() ){
        jQuery(this).val("");
    }
})

jQuery("#dfwylf_Overlay input:text").blur(function(){
    console.log(jQuery(this).attr("value"));
    //the above outputs empty
    if ( jQuery(this).val() == "" ){
        jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).attr("value"));
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dfwylf_Overlay">
<input type="text" name="someName" id="someId" value="a value">
<input type="text" name="someName2" id="someId2" value="another value">
</div>
```